# Undefined variable error when rendering partial on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial

I am trying to put render code in my edit.html.erb and create _form.html.erb.
I have these code for edit.html.erb

```
    <h1>Main#edit</h1>
    <h1>Editing zone</h1>
    <%= render partial: "form", locals: {addresses: @addresses} %>
```

and these code for _form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(addresses)do |f| %>
  <p>
  <b>name</b><br>
  <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

and addresses is a set of address.

and I have this erro:
      Couldn't find Address with 'id'=
      Extracted source (around line #21):

```
  def edit
 @address = Address.find(params[:id])  this is 21th line
  if request.post?
  if (@address.update_attributes(address_params))
  redirect_to :action=>"index"
```

would you please help to check anything wrong in my code?

here is the code of my controller:

```
    class MainController < ApplicationController
    def index
    @addresses = Address.all
    end

    def new

    end

    def add
    address = Address.new(address_params)
    if (address.save)
    redirect_to :action=>"index"
    else
     flash[:notice]="Error saving, try again"
     redirect_to :action=>"index"
     end
    end

    def edit
    @address = Address.find(params[:id])
    if request.post?
    if (@address.update_attributes(address_params))
    redirect_to :action=>"index"
    else
    render :action=>"edit"
        end
      end
    end

    def delete
    address = Address.find(params[:id])
    address.destroy
    redirect_to :action=>"index"
    end

    private
    def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:name,:address,:email,:phone)
    end
    end
```

here is my model:
[my data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiGZE.png)

Comment: The original code is in https://github.com/siddharthkaza/addressbook_rails42.git. Sorry, it's not undefined variable error, I also like to know how the _form call edit function. I don't understand, if I need to pass id value, where I specify it?

Comment: I don't know how partial render works in rails.  I think problem problem may either because I forget pass id value to edit function, or my address is somehow not read( I am sure addresses[1] and more are not empty).

Comment: (1) you should spend a **little** more time formatting your code, (2) you should post the specific stack trace.

Comment: sorry I am puzzled by this too..I don't know the trace so I am confusing. It is a common sample. Partial render both in new and edit view, but I don't know how it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see more of your controller code, but it looks like Rails is trying to find an address matching the id within `params` here:

```
 def edit
   @address = Address.find(params[:id])
```

It seems like you have a route setup to handle this edit action:

```
get 'resource/:id', to: 'ResourceController#edit'
```

When you try to access '/resource/1' (or whatever your url is) in your browser, it should find the address (assuming there is an address with id=1 in your database)

Comment: I added more info, would you please check again? Address here is just an attribute.